# Pointing to All Three views inside SwiftUI from a ViewRouter and ObservableObjects or environmentObject's

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, observableobject

I have been using SwiftUI lately, and I have managed to write in ContentView.swift as my rootView, including 2 buttons to change to other "pages" or "screens" within an app. Currently, I am able to move between Two views in my code. I used ObservableObjects(viewRouter : ViewRouter) in each "screen" swift file. I decided to write a third screen to pop up for a user to view. After including the same structures and ways to bring up that view : The Button's Action for the third view is not being ran. **There are no errors in compiling, the app will build!** But, the ThirdScreen is not visible when clicking the button inside FirstScreen.

Here is the Main View ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var screen: String = "FirstScreen" //Declares the first state
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter : ViewRouter //References our other swift file.

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            if viewRouter.currentScreen == "FirstScreen" {
                FirstScreen()
                    } else if viewRouter.currentScreen == "SecondScreen" {
                SecondScreen()
                    .transition(.slide)
            } else if viewRouter.currentScreen == "ThirdScreen" {
                ThirdScreen()
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider { //Looks fine, its the previews
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())}}
```

Here is the FirstScreen file with its structure below:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
struct FirstScreen : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter : ViewRouter
    var body : some View {
    VStack {
    Button(action: {
            print("The info button has been clicked.")
        self.viewRouter.currentScreen = "SecondScreen" //Heres an action
           }) {
               Image(systemName: "info")
                   .padding()
                   .background(Color.green)
                   .font(.largeTitle)
                   .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                   .frame(width: 300, height: 600)           
           }     
           Button(action: {
               print("You have erased it.")
            self.viewRouter.currentScreen = "ThirdScreen" //This action does not happen.
           }) {
               Image(systemName: "trash")
               .padding()
                   .background(Color.red)
                   .font(.largeTitle)
                   .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                   .frame(width: 426, height: 620)
}}}}
struct FirstScreen_previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstScreen().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my ThirdScreen which should be loaded in from ViewRouter and the change from clicking the button from the FirstScreen's Swift file.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
struct ThirdScreen : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter : ViewRouter
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You step a bit off balance")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            Text("You stand up, shaking, under a pass")
                .font(.callout)
            Text("It looks to be a wrong step. Maybe you head back?")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            Button(action :{self.viewRouter.currentScreen = "FirstScreen"}){
                Image(systemName: "capslock" )
                    .frame(width: 209, height: 308)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
}}}}
struct Third_preview : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ThirdScreen().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewRouter.swift which works fine to manage screens.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter, Never>()
    var currentScreen : String = "FirstScreen" {
        didSet {
            withAnimation(){
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Lastly, my correctly working SecondScreen.swift. This file is probably redundant, but I included it on the off chance that something good is working inside this file. As buttons work inside to change views.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
struct SecondScreen : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter : ViewRouter

    var body : some View {
    VStack { 
 Button(action: {self.viewRouter.currentScreen = "FirstScreen"}) {
            Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.left" )
            .padding()
            .cornerRadius(18)
                .frame(width: 180, height: 400)
}}}}
struct SecondScreen_previews : PreviewProvider{
    static var previews : some View {
        SecondScreen().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

Thank you extremely for helping me here. I would love to continue making Screen files as the they are below, I just wonder why my third screen isn't pulled up. I will be responding quickly as I continue to troubleshoot this. Thank you!

Comment: Works fine. Tested with Xcode 11.4. Have you test it in Simulator or Preview?

Comment: @Asperi Were you able to click the red icon in simulator and view the ThirdScreen view? I was having an issue viewing it, as my code also ran and built itself, however the button function did not go through using simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!solved Ran a few more tests on the code using other action types for buttons, and was able to view the next screen.